# Constant stroke width rectangle with FabricJS

Tags: fabricjs

Is there any way to draw rectangles using FabricJs with constant width strokes?

On every example I could find, you can set the stroke width but when you resize the rectangle, the stroke is scaled together with the shape.

Comment: @ℊααnd I found these two fiddles with working solutions http://jsfiddle.net/jesseh77/bH93k/   http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/nawLjtn8/

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the game here but I wanted to document this somewhere. The fiddle from davidtorroija (http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/nawLjtn8/) shared in the above comment was nearly a perfect solution for me, but it has a big issue. Fabric uses values called "cacheWidth" and "cacheHeight", and without changing those as well, you can end up with some dodgy rendering not matching the specified height and widths:

Without changing the cached values:
https://i.gyazo.com/6cc1223444309cd55715bd81aa9dcb39.gif

With changing the cached values:
https://i.gyazo.com/e842b57af255460fcdbdc3533a6793e6.gif

Something like this should do the trick

```
// Existing code
this.width *= this.scaleX
this.height *= this.scaleY
// New code
this.cacheWidth = this.width
this.cacheHeight = this.height
```